# Debug vaadin applications on the client side

Tags: debugging, gwt, logging, vaadin, vaadin7

I am on an update from vaadin 6 to vaadin 7 and I am trying to find a way to debug the project on the client side. I have tried to launch the [debug procedure](http://morevaadin.com/content/debugging-vaadin-client-widgets/) , but with no effect. I am using `Windows 8` and when trying to install the `gwt-plugin` I see the message:

```
"The installation of this software is not allowed on this machine".
```

Therefore I want at least to be able to send messages in the debug window, as with `VConsole` in `vaadin 6`. Strangely this deprecated in vaadin 7 class  does not respond in vaadin 7 project in my working environment, namely I cannot see the messages anywhere. Any possible reason of that? 
[It is proposed though to use Logger](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.logging.html) instead, but I still cannot understand two things:

1) How should the `logging.properties` look like?

2) Where I see the output of logging messages?

Any other sugesstions would be appreciated.

Comment: Logging is implemented with standard java libraries and is handled by application server (not Vaadin). Address your app server (Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss, etc.) documentation to find a location of log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VConsole.log - whilst deprecated in Vaadin 7- still works. Two things to bear in mind

1) The webapp cannot be in "production" mode - i.e. the productionMode in web.xml must be set to false
2) Typically, you need to be in Debug mode - i.e. add  the debug parameter to the request URL in the browser e.g. `http://localhost:8080/my-application?debug`

See [this page in Vaadin Book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.debug.html) for more details.

The debug logging will appear in the debug window that appears inside your application. It should also appear in the javascript console of the browser.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works. The problem was on the compilation of Widgetset, which did not allow the new clients side to run and it let an older version run instead. Of course, it is more elegant for someone to use Logger instead of the old-fashioned VConsole.